# Можно ли задавать offset в шестнадцатиричной системе

Tags: ассемблер, mips

Когда мы загружаем значение:

```
lw $s0, 0x32(0x47383993)
```

имеем ли мы право записывать именно в шестнадцатиричной системе оффсет, или надо переводить в десятичную?

Comment: во всех языках принято, если в языке поддерживается указание системы счисления в виде префиксов вроде 0x то это поддерживается везде. Так что да, система счисления может применяться и тут. НО вы уверены, что вообще так можно, написать две константы. Какой в этом смысл ? На сколько я понял при беглом осмотре системы команд MIPS там возможна либо прямая адресация, по четко указанному адресу `lw $s0, 0x473839C5` (хотя там наверно только 16 бит возможны), либо косвенная, относительно какого либо регистра `lw $s0, 0x32($s0)` т.е. в скобках может быть только регистр, но не константа

Comment: Кстати да, ведь у MIPS на сколько я знаю ограниченный размер инструкции и в нее влезает только 16 бит данных. А значит команда `lw $s0, 0x32(0x47383993)` принципиально невозможна, потому что такой большой адрес просто невозможно уложить в инструкцию. Собственно поэтому и придумана косвенная адресация с использованием регистров

Comment: Спасибо большое.